# consuming sharepoint 2010 web service with visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to consume a SharePoint 2010 web service via Visual Studio 2010.  I want to download all files of a document library which can only be accessed to authenticated users. No tutorial I found worked. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code: Please try below function. you need to pass FileURL(Full web url for document), Title(Pass name you want to give for downloaded file.)

(Note: this function need to pass credentials along with full url for the document you want to download. I think that would be enough for you)

```
public string DownLoadfiletolocal(string FileURL, string Title)
{

//Copy.Copy is a webservice object that I consumed.

Copy.Copy CopyObj = new Copy.Copy();
CopyObj.Url = SiteURL + "/_vti_bin/copy.asmx"; // Dynamically passing SiteURL
NetworkCredential nc2 = new NetworkCredential();
nc2.Domain = string.Empty;
nc2.UserName = _UserName;
nc2.Password = _Password;


string copySource = FileURL; //Pass full url for document.

Copy.FieldInformation myFieldInfo = new Copy.FieldInformation();
Copy.FieldInformation[] myFieldInfoArray = { myFieldInfo };
byte[] myByteArray;

// Call the web service
uint myGetUint = CopyObj.GetItem(copySource, out myFieldInfoArray, out myByteArray);

// Convert into Base64 String
string base64String;
base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(myByteArray, 0, myByteArray.Length);

// Convert to binary array
byte[] binaryData = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);

// Create a temporary file to write the text of the form to
string tempFileName = Path.GetTempPath() + "\\" + Title;

// Write the file to temp folder
FileStream fs = new FileStream(tempFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
fs.Write(binaryData, 0, binaryData.Length);
fs.Close();

return tempFileName;

}
```

Comment: Thank you, i would use your code if i already could get the list of documents within a document library.

Comment: I added a service reference to the copy.asmx Service, but theres no copy interface. Only CopySoap.

Comment: use Web Reference add this service not added in Service Reference